# Webpart, bad TitleIconImageUrl url

Tags: web-part, xml, catalog

My website url is: mysupersite.com/sites/thesite

I want to put an image with TitleIconImageUrl in the webpart.

I have:

```
    <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string">/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png</property>
```

The generate url is

```
mysupersite.com/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png
```

instead of

```
mysupersite.com/sites/thesite/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png
```

What can i do to say to sharepoint to use my Fav.png in the good place ?

Comment: SO you to use mysupersite.com/sites/thesite/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png??

Comment: It's the dev url. The prod url will be othersite.com/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png

Comment: So in production site when you deploy that web part to that site, it will generate the same.

Comment: I don't understand. It will generate the url mysupersite.com/sites/thesite/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png in the production site ?

Comment: It will be relative url, if you deploy to mysupersite.com then url be mysupersite.com/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png  and if you deploy to mysupersite.com/sites/thesite the url will be mysupersite.com/sites/thesite/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png. It is just relative path

Comment: that's what I thought but the generate url (with the current code) is mysupersite.com/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png instead of mysupersite.com/sites/thesite/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png. That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your webpart code behind:

this.TitleIconImageUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/Fav.png");

It might solve your issue.